# TypeError: object of none types has no len()

Tags: python

My code is below. I get the "TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"

```
def minsum(nums: List[int])->int:
  i=1
  while i<len(nums):
    nums=nums.remove(min(nums))
    i+=1
  return sum(nums)
```

But if I just write this, it works:

```
def minsum(nums: List[int])->int:
  return len(nums)
```

Comment: Have you tried to do any debugging on your own? Like `print(nums)` in various places to see what's going on?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

`nums.remove()` modifies the list in place, it doesn't return a new list. So when you assign the result to `nums`, you're setting it to `None`.

Change

```
none = none.remove(min(nums))
```

to just

```
none.remove(min(nums))
```